# Describe in words how a NTM can simulate a DTM

Tags: turing-machines, nondeterminism

I have this assignment

1. Describe in words how a DTM can simulate a NTM
2. Describe in wordshow a NTM can simulate a DTM

---

I'm working on this request and I'm crushing with the comparison.

1-I understand that every NTM can be represented by a DTM with a tree structure, that represents every step of the different possibilities of a NTM. Every step should simulate with n tapes the configuration states of the NTM with the DTM etc.

2-For this I'm a little lost, I think you can't have a DTM simulated by an NTM, the multiplicity of states allowed in NTM with guesses makes difficult to create a deterministic process o linear, ¿I'm going in the right path?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NDTM may use multiple transitions which are **allowed**, but these are **not required**. Think of it in another way, DTM is already NDTM that doesn't use possibility of multiple paths, so it is not much of simulation.

Comment: Thanks!, you point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

A nondeterministic Turing machine has zero or more possible transitions in every configuration; a deterministic one has exactly one. One is "zero or more".